# set disabled on a form item through form ref

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am currently using `antd-form-builder` to build multiple JSON forms for different components and I have an issue with antd trying to use a checkbox to disable another input.. basically I have a function that returns the form `meta` fields and then in the `onChange` for the checkbox I am trying to set another field to become disabled

what I have managed to find so far is for the form ref there is a `setFields` function and I can use this to change the value of another field or the errors on that field through the `onChange` of the checkbox, however, I cannot change the disabled state of another field.

Comment: can you provide relevant code snippets? It's better if you can provide a repo or https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out, this cant be done .. and state variables should be used as mentioned in the issue [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/30876)